# QGLWidget interop with WPF

Tags: c#, c++, .net, qt, opengl

I was wondering if there was a way to place a Qt QGLWidget, in order to render OpenGL, inside of a WPF window. This would make it easy to create a great application around the QGLWidget i.e. a game editor.